Java ZonedDateTime.parse not working as expected
I am using Java 17. I am trying to parse different strings as ZonedDateTime but when I try to convert it to an Instant, the output is not as expected. For eg:
        String first = "2020-01-08T21:00:00Z[Europe/Berlin]";
        ZonedDateTime zone1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(first);
        String second = "2020-01-08T20:00:00Z[UTC]";
        ZonedDateTime zone2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(second);
        System.out.println(zone1.toInstant());
        System.out.println(zone2.toInstant());

The output is (this is wrong, both times should be same):
2020-01-08T21:00:00Z
2020-01-08T20:00:00Z

However, when I create a ZonedDateTime object using constructor and ZoneId I get correct output:
        ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.of(2020,1,8,21,0,0,0,ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
        System.out.println(z1.toInstant());
        
        ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.of(2020,1,8,20,0,0,0,ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        System.out.println(z2.toInstant());

Output:
2020-01-08T20:00:00Z
2020-01-08T20:00:00Z

Can anyone tell me why my parse method is not working as expected?
Note: This issue is NOT related to DST bug for ZonedTimeZone in JDK8:

Doesn't "Z" mean "Zulu Time", UTC?

I'm surprised that the library doesn't throw an exception complaining that "Z" and "Berlin" are conflicting.

@k314159 maybe contra-intuitive, but from the documentation we get "The ISO-like date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with offset and zone ... extends the ISO-8601 extended offset date-time format to add the time-zone." (emphasis added)

In Java 8 the parse method would respect the time zone and ignore the UTC offset ( Z meaning offset 0 in your case). It was considered a bug and was fixed so that today the offset is respected no matter if it disagrees with the time zone. Seems you can’t make everyone happy.

Yes, @AndyTurner, it certainly does.

To ignore the UTC offset from the string: Parse date and time using LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(first, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);. Parse the time zone using ZoneId zid = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parse(first, ZoneId::from);. Obtain your ZonedDateTime with ldt.atZone(zid). In case of your string first we get 2020-01-08T21:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin], which converts to an Instant of 2020-01-08T20:00:00Z as requested. Beware of unpredictable results in the time overlap at fall back where summer time ends.

@Anonymous Is there any documentation regarding that bug?

It’s in the bug database. Unfortunately searching the bug database doesn’t work just these days, so I can’t find it for you. It’s certainly been mentioned on Stack Overflow before too, sorry that a quick search I did here didn’t find it.

Thanks @Anonymous The questions wasn't rhetorical

In your input string "2020-01-08T21:00:00Z[Europe/Berlin]" (and the second one) remove 'Z' as that means that it is a UTC time and subsequent timezone is ignored. So, both of your times are in UTC meaning that the first one is NOT in [Europe/Berlin] time zone. You might want to parse the strings using format mask using DateTimeFormatter class. Or replace 'Z' with '+01:00' and then you don't need to use formatting.
